# Autolayout: Incorrect Width when using ScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, scrollview, autolayout

i´m using autolayout and followed the instruction from this guide:

http://www.g8production.com/post/57513133020/auto-layout-with-uiscrollview-how-to-use

I build my View with a xib File and Interface Builder. This is my Tree:

-UIView

--UIScrollView

---UIView (ContentView)

----SubViews

The Problem is that when i only put **ONE!** Subview (an UIImageView) inside the ContentView and set a Left,Top and Right Constraint to the Subview, i get a warning which says: Autolayout expected a width of 1000!! I have no Idea why it gets so broken. All my Views have a width of 320px so that couldn´t be the Problem. 
Here some Screenshots which may help:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UIImageView.image.size.width` is 1000 in your case. So it's following it's own intrinsic content size and expanding itself with respect to own intrinsic content size. You can follow one of the method so solve this:

**Method 1:-** Add `width` constraint of contentView, so UIImageView will adopt the width of contentView.

**Method 2:-** Add `width` constraint of UIImageView, so contentView will adopt the width of UIImageView.

**Method 3:-** Add `Equal Width` constraint on your contentView and UIScrollView. so contentView will adopt the scrollView width, and UIImageView will adopt contentView width.

You can get more details here about the `contents intrinsic content size`:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Answer (score 1):

Inspect each of the constraints and check the value of its `constant` parameter, and make sure they are 0 or whatever you were expecting. Interface Builder has the annoying habit of taking the size that was on the canvas at the time you create a constraint.

Comment: I checked everything, but its correct...really strange -_-